# How to write calculated values to SQL INSERT/UPDATE in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-4.0

In my below PowerShell I am getting all first level folders in a UNC path, and make a calculation of each of these folders count of files, folders and size in MB, which I need written into a SQL Server table, but this gives me some headaches on writing the values to the SQL string.

I have 3 values that I need to write to the SQL which are:

- $TotalFileCount
- $TotalDirectoryCount
- $TotalFolderSizeInMB'

I have tried to write them out like:

- $TotalFileCount
- $($TotalFileCount)
- $($TotalFileCount.tostring()
- $($TotalFileCount.value.tostring())

But none of them returns any data when I make a `Write-Host`, so I expect that it is because `$TotalFileCount` is a calculation, but any effort to find a solution to write this out have been effortless, so I need some help to find a solution.

My PS script:

```
 $SQLServer = "SQL_SERVER"
 $SQLDatabase = "DATA_BASE"
    
    #SQL function
    function Invoke-SQL {
        param(
            [string] $sqlCommand = $(throw "Please specify a query.")
          )
    
        $connectionString = "Data Source=$SQLServer; " +
                "Integrated Security=SSPI; " +
                "Initial Catalog=$SQLDatabase"
    
        $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
        $command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)
        $connection.Open()
        
        $adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
        $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        
        $connection.Close()
        $dataSet.Tables
    }
    
    Function Get-DirectoryTreeSize {
    
     
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Default")]
     
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Position = 0,
            Mandatory = $true
        )]
        [string]  $Path,
     
     
     
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ParameterSetName = "ShowRecursive"
        )]
        [switch]  $Recurse,
     
     
     
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ParameterSetName = "ShowTopFolderAllItemsAndAllFolders"
        )]
        [switch]  $AllItemsAndAllFolders
    )
     
        BEGIN {
            #Adding a trailing slash at the end of $path to make it consistent.
            if (-not $Path.EndsWith('\')) {
                $Path = "$Path\"
            }
        }
     
        PROCESS {
            try {
                if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("AllItemsAndAllFolders") -and -not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("Recurse")) {
                    $FileStats = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -ErrorAction Stop | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
                    $FileCount = $FileStats.Count
                    $DirectoryCount = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count
                    $SizeMB =  "{0:F3}" -f ($FileStats.Sum / 1MB) -as [decimal]
     
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Path                 = $Path
                        FileCount            = $FileCount
                        DirectoryCount       = $DirectoryCount
                        FolderSizeInMB       = $SizeMB
                    }
                }
     
                if  ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("AllItemsAndAllFolders")) {
                    $FileStats = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
                    $FileCount = $FileStats.Count
                    $DirectoryCount = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory -Recurse | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count
                    $SizeMB =  "{0:F3}" -f ($FileStats.Sum / 1MB) -as [decimal]
     
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Path                 = $Path
                        TotalFileCount       = $FileCount
                        TotalDirectoryCount  = $DirectoryCount
                        TotalFolderSizeInMB  = $SizeMB
                    }
                }
     
                if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("Recurse")) {
                    Get-DirectoryTreeSize -Path $Path
                    $FolderList = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName
     
                    if ($FolderList) {
                        foreach ($Folder in $FolderList) {
                            $FileStats = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -File | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
                            $FileCount = $FileStats.Count
                            $DirectoryCount = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Directory | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count
                            $SizeMB =  "{0:F3}" -f ($FileStats.Sum / 1MB) -as [decimal]
     
                            [PSCustomObject]@{
                                Path                 = $Folder
                                FileCount            = $FileCount
                                DirectoryCount       = $DirectoryCount
                                FolderSizeInMB       = $SizeMB
                            }
                            #clearing variables
                            $null = $FileStats
                            $null = $FileCount
                            $null = $DirectoryCount
                            $null = $SizeMB
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
            }
     
        }
     
        END {}
     
    }
    
    
    foreach ($name in Get-ChildItem "\\FILSRV01\home dir$"| Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object name)
    {
        $TopPath = "\\FILSRV01\home dir$\"
    
        $TempPath = Join-Path $TopPath $name."name"
        
        Get-DirectoryTreeSize $TempPath -AllItemsAndAllFolders
    
   
        $sqlSelectCommand = "SELECT * from EFP_HomeFolder_Stats where UserInitials = '$($name."name")'"
        $sqlInsertCommand = "INSERT INTO EFP_HomeFolder_Stats (Path,UserInitials,TotalFileCount,TotalDirectoryCount,TotalFolderSizeInMB,LastUpdated) VALUES('$TempPath','$($name."name")','$($TotalFileCount)','$TotalDirectoryCount','$TotalFolderSizeInMB',GETDATE())"
        $sqlUpdateCommand = "UPDATE EFP_HomeFolder_Stats SET Path = '$TempPath', UserInitials = '$($name."name")', TotalFileCount = '$TotalFileCount', TotalDirectoryCount = '$TotalDirectoryCount', TotalFolderSizeInMB = '$TotalFolderSizeInMB', LastUpdated = GETDATE()"
    
        Invoke-SQL -sqlCommand $sqlSelectCommand
    
        Write-host $name.ExistCoun
    
    
        Invoke-SQL -sqlCommand "
    
            if exists ($sqlSelectCommand)            
            BEGIN            
                $sqlUpdateCommand
            End                    
            else            
            BEGIN
                $sqlInsertCommand
            END 
            "
    }
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/

Comment: Hi @shawnt00 I might be overseeing something regarding your link, but I have already tried this as you see in post

Comment: Is it possibly the quotes? Is anything inserted at all?

Comment: Removing the quotes does not change anything .. At the moment SQL is not inserting, I was aware of that, but wanted to take one issue at a time, and my first concern was that no value  is written when I write out the sql command . i.e `INSERT INTO EFP_HomeFolder_Stats (Path,UserInitials,TotalFileCount,TotalDirectoryCount,TotalFolderSizeInMB,LastUpdated) VALUES('\\FILSRV01\home dir$\MWE','MWE',,,,GETDATE())` and `UPDATE EFP_HomeFolder_Stats SET Path = '\\FILSRV01\home dir$\CAN', UserInitials = 'CAN', TotalFileCount = , TotalDirectoryCount = , TotalFolderSizeInMB = , LastUpdated = GETDATE()`

Comment: The counts don't get a value in either the sql statements. That's definitely going to error.

Comment: Yes, thats why I have concentrated on how to get these counts written out ..  clock is 02:21 am here so must get some sleep and look at this tomorrow with fresh eyes.

Comment: @shawnt00 I have now looked at it a few more times, testet acording to the link with different variations, but I cannot get it to work, at best it writes out '0' but not the correct value. If you still means that I am overseeing something in the link I need a little more help than the link.

Comment: I'm not a PS expert at all. At first I thought it was an issue with string-building. Are you sure those properties are even being calculate correctly to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Yes they are, the output I get to the PS Screen is correct calculated .. from what I have been able to figure out For the issue is that I need to put the results from Get-DirectoryTreeSize in to a variable to access the objects that it returns, but at the moment I have no clue on how to do that since what I have tried so far has failed - however I am able to Write-Output from within the function like `Write-Output $FileStats.Count`, `Write-Output $DirectoryCount`, `Write-Output $SizeMB` but in my loop if I do so, because it is outside function, I cannot.

Comment: Is it a scope problem? Are the values still around once you get to the SQL part?

Comment: Yes I think it is a scope issue - perhaps - I my self are no PS expert eigther :-D .. And no it seems that the variables are not present when I get to the foreach part and that I think is the issue, but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: @shawnt00 check out my answer I have just posted where I have the solution .. if you have any suggestions regarding my left SQL issue I would be happy to hear you thoughts :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed the issue that no variables where written to my SQL INSERT/UPDATE query by moving the the Invoke-SQL inside the `Get-DirectoryTreeSize` function and values are now being populated to my query when i do a Write-OutPut of the query. The UserInitials I now get by `$MySplitPath = Split-Path -Path $Path -Leaf`instead of `$name."name"`  ..

Issue left is that the SQL does not execute, meaning nothing is beeing inserted to my SQL table, so I need to figure that part out now. If anyone have a suggestion I would be happy to here it :-)

```
#statiske vaiabler
$SQLServer = "SQL_SERVER"
$SQLDatabase = "SQL_DB"

#SQL function
function Invoke-SQL {
    param(
        [string] $sqlCommand = $(throw "Please specify a query.")
      )

    $connectionString = "Data Source=$SQLServer; " +
            "Integrated Security=SSPI; " +
            "Initial Catalog=$SQLDatabase"

    $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
    $command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)
    $connection.Open()
    
    $adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
    $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    
    $connection.Close()
    $dataSet.Tables
}

Function Get-DirectoryTreeSize {

 
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Default")]
 
param(
    [Parameter(
        Position = 0,
        Mandatory = $true
    )]
    [string]  $Path,
 
 
 
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $false,
        ParameterSetName = "ShowRecursive"
    )]
    [switch]  $Recurse,
 
 
 
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $false,
        ParameterSetName = "ShowTopFolderAllItemsAndAllFolders"
    )]
    [switch]  $AllItemsAndAllFolders
)
 
    BEGIN {
        #Adding a trailing slash at the end of $path to make it consistent.
        if (-not $Path.EndsWith('\')) {
            $Path = "$Path\"

        }
        if ($Path.EndsWith('\')) {
            $Path = "$Path\"

        }
    }
 
    PROCESS {
        try {
            if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("AllItemsAndAllFolders") -and -not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("Recurse")) {
                $FileStats = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -ErrorAction Stop | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
                $FileCount = $FileStats.Count
                $DirectoryCount = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count
                $SizeMB =  "{0:F3}" -f ($FileStats.Sum / 1MB) -as [decimal]
 
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Path                 = $Path
                    FileCount            = $FileCount
                    DirectoryCount       = $DirectoryCount
                    FolderSizeInMB       = $SizeMB
                }
            }
 
            if  ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("AllItemsAndAllFolders")) {
                $FileStats = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
                $FileCount = $FileStats.Count
                $DirectoryCount = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory -Recurse | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count
                $SizeMB =  "{0:F3}" -f ($FileStats.Sum / 1024) -as [decimal]

                      $MySplitPath = Split-Path -Path $Path -Leaf  

                      Invoke-SQL -sqlCommand = "

                      IF EXISTS (SELECT * from EFP_HomeFolder_Stats where UserInitials = '$MySplitPath')
                      BEGIN
                        UPDATE EFP_HomeFolder_Stats SET UserInitials = '$MySplitPath', TotalFileCount = $FileStats.Count, TotalDirectoryCount = $DirectoryCount, TotalFolderSizeInMB = $SizeMB, LastUpdated = GETDATE()
                      END
                      ELSE
                      BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO EFP_HomeFolder_Stats (UserInitials,TotalFileCount,TotalDirectoryCount,TotalFolderSizeInMB,LastUpdated) VALUES('$MySplitPath',$FileStats.Count,$DirectoryCount,$SizeMB,GETDATE());
                      END
                                            
                      "

            }
 
            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("Recurse")) {
                Get-DirectoryTreeSize -Path $Path
                $FolderList = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName
 
                if ($FolderList) {
                    foreach ($Folder in $FolderList) {
                        $FileStats = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -File | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
                        $FileCount = $FileStats.Count
                        $DirectoryCount = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Directory | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count
                        $SizeMB =  "{0:F3}" -f ($FileStats.Sum / 1MB) -as [decimal]
 
                        [PSCustomObject]@{
                            Path                 = $Folder
                            FileCount            = $FileCount
                            DirectoryCount       = $DirectoryCount
                            FolderSizeInMB       = $SizeMB
                        }
                        #clearing variables
                        $null = $FileStats
                        $null = $FileCount
                        $null = $DirectoryCount
                        $null = $SizeMB
                        

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }
 
    }

    END {}
 
}



foreach ($name in Get-ChildItem "\\FILSRV01\home dir$"| Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object name)
{
    
    Write-Output $($null)
    
    $TopPath = "\\FILSRV01\home dir$\"

    $TempPath = Join-Path $TopPath $name."name"
    
    Get-DirectoryTreeSize $TempPath -AllItemsAndAllFolders

}
```